# Inverse of a Uniform(4,5) CDF

Tags: probability, random-variables, inverse, uniform-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose $X$ follows a Uniform(4, 5) with CDF
$$F_X(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x \ge 5 \\ x-4, & 4 < x < 5 \\ 0, & x \le 4 \end{cases}.$$

Is the correct inverse of the above CDF the following?
$$F_{X}^{-1}(u) = \begin{cases} 1, & u \ge 5 \\ u+4, & 4 < u < 5 \\ 0, & u \le 4 \end{cases}.$$

Comment: Notice that $F:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$. Thus $F^{-1}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. In your setting, $u=0$ returns $(-\infty,4]$, $u\in (0,1)$ returns $4+u$ and $u=1$ returns $[5,\infty)$. Notice that $F^{-1}$ is returning an interval for the two values $0$ and $1$, since you don't have a bijection. Thus, you should talk of the inverse only if you restrict the function to $F:[4,5]\to[0,1]$, in this way you can talk about the inverse of $f$ as a function.

Comment: @Cuoredicervo so to correct what I said above, the bounds should be like this? $F_{X}^{-1}(u) = \begin{cases} 1, & u \ge 1 \\ u+4, & 0 < u < 1 \\ 0, & u \le 0 \end{cases}$

Comment: Assuming that $F_X:[4,5]\to[0,1]$, then $$F^{-1}_X(u)=\begin{cases}5, & u=1 \\ u+4, & 0<u<1 \\ 4, &u=0 \end{cases}$$ which can simply be written as $F^{-1}_X(u)=u+4$ for $0\leq u\leq 1$.